# extract value from xml data column oracle sql

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

From the database there is a column which contains xml data in the format like:

```
       <old_template_code> something </old_template_code><old_template_name> new  
       code</old_template_name><new_template_code>BEVA24M</new_template_code>
```

How can I extract the values from the xml and make a column for each of the different xml values? For example I would like to do something like:

```
       select EXTRACTVALUE(table.column, table.column)
```

but the latter doesn't work for me.

Comment: Please show us your expected result for the example XML data you posted in your question.